# PySpark - Is there a way to iterate over multiple columns and fill NAs with the column's max number(+1)?

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, pyspark, null

I have a PySpark dataframe with Nulls in multiple columns. I am trying to fill the nulls with the respective column's max number + 1. The idea is to go back and mark these values as "None" after one hot encoding in trying to mimic the one hot encoding process in SAS when creating a "missing" category for each numeric categorical columns.

For example,'null' in male should be '3'. So, the max num of male column + 1 = 3. Then 4, and 6 for the other cols.

Example data:

```
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
|              MS|  male| rate|level|
+----------------+------+-----+-----+-
|         Married|  null| null|    5|
|         Married|     1|    2|    2|
|        Divorced|     2|    3| null|
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
```

Here is some of what I have tried thus far. But it's either not filling in the nulls or it fills '6' in to all the columns.

```
null_list = ['male', 'rate', 'level']
descr_dict = {'male': '2', 'rate': '3', 'level': '5'}

for c in spark_data.columns:
    if c in null_list:
        for key, value in descr_dict.items():
            max_val = int(value) + 1
            df = spark_data.withColumn(c, F.when((spark_data[c]==key) & 
                 (spark_data[c].isNull())), 
                  F.lit(max_val)).otherwise(spark_data[c]))
```

Expected data:

```
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
|              MS|  male| rate|level|
+----------------+------+-----+-----+-
|         Married|     3|    4|    5|
|         Married|     1|    2|    2|
|        Divorced|     2|    3|    6|
+----------------+------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the columns of the `DataFrame` as you did, and then calculate the max of the column.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd

for colnm in sdf.schema.names:
    if colnm.lower() not in ['ms']:
        sdf = sdf. \
            withColumn(colnm, 
                       func.when(func.col(colnm).isNull(), func.max(colnm).over(wd.partitionBy(func.lit(1))) + func.lit(1)).
                       otherwise(func.col(colnm))
                       )
```

This is similar to what you have in mind. Just calculating the max there itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataFrame.fillna` accepts a dictionary that can have keys you would like to fill. *e.g.*

```py
fill_values = {
  k: int(v) + 1
  for k, v in descr_dict.items()
}
sdf = sdf.na.fill(fill_values)
```